# How to insert newline while logging lists and arrays?

Tags: python, list, logging

I am trying to output lists to a log file, using Python's logging module. The code I used is:

```
import logging
import os
logging.basicConfig(filename = 'Log.log', level = logging.DEBUG, filemode = 'w', format = '%(asctime)s \t %(levelname)s \t %(message)s', datefmt="[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]")
file_list = []
for root, directories, files in os.walk('./Directory'):
    files = [f for f in files]
    for file in files:
        file_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))
logging.info('Files in list: %s', file_list)
```

This gives me the output in the log file as a single line.

**Output**

```
[2015-03-14 11:41:53]    INFO    Files in list: ['./Directory/Subdirectory 1/file_a.dat', './Directory/Subdirectory 1/file_1b.dat', './Directory/Subdirectory 1/Subdirectory 11/file_11a.dat', './Directory/Subdirectory 1/Subdirectory 11/Subdirectory 111/file_111a.dat', './Directory/Subdirectory 2/Subdirectory 22/Subdirectory 221/file_221a.dat', './Directory/Subdirectory 2/Subdirectory 22/Subdirectory 221/file_221b.dat', './Directory/Subdirectory 2/Subdirectory 22/Subdirectory 221/file_221c.dat']
```

What I require is only the file names in the list in a new line.

**Desired output**

```
[2015-03-14 11:41:53]    INFO    Files in list: file_a.dat
                                 file_1b.dat
                                 file_11a.dat
                                 file_111a.dat
                                 file_221a.dat
                                 file_221b.dat
                                 file_221c.dat
```

How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'\n'.join` to merge strings with newline as separator and a generator expression to remove the directory names:

```
logging.info('Files in list: %s', '\n'.join(os.path.basename(f)
                                            for f in file_list)))
```

Comment: This will not, however, indent the output as shown in the desired output section of the question. That *may* be fine, matching that indentation is going to be hard without knowing up-front what the formatters are set to (there can be more than one!)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point, I assumed the indentation was provided by the smart newline handling by a standard formatter.

Answer (score 2):

Use standard [Pretty Print](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module:

```
from pprint import pformat
logging.info('Files in list:\n%s', pformat(file_list))
```

Output example:

```
[2015-03-14 14:23:47]    INFO    Files in list:
['./tmpvYWsRB.png',
 './Log.log',
 './tmpCG2Dn2',
 './ tmp7I36mh.png',
```

To print filenames only, use standard [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) as user4815162342 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the generic way to do this for a list of tuples. Probably not the best way though, but has the least dependencies:

Tldr; Brute Force it.

```
print('\n'.join(str(my_list_of_tuples).split('),')))
```